# How do you initialise an Angular 4 model from the serving ASP.NET MVC page?

Tags: angular

I would like to initialise an Angular 4 application's model with some data that I supply on my ASP.NET MVC razor generated page. [I suggest however that the server rendering mechanism is irrelevant.]

I've attempted to construct the minimum viable example below.

To start I created the application using `ng new stackoverflow-question`. Then I edited the following files:

### src/index.html

This page would normally be generated on the server side, but for simplicity:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>StackOverflow</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  // I want this data to be injected into my Angular app's someDataFromTheHostPage field.
  // The below would normally be generated by server-side code.
  var someData = [
      { name: 'fido', kind: 'dog' },
      { name: 'mittens', kind: 'cat' },
      { name: 'gingernut', kind: 'hamster' }
    ];
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### src/app/app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  // I want this to be set by script on the page
  someDataFromTheHostPage : object = null;
}
```

### src/app/app.component.html

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!
  </h1>
</div>
<h2>Here is the data from the host page: </h2>
<pre>
  {{someDataFromTheHostPage | json}}
</pre>
```

So, to reiterate the inline comments from the code above: I'm after a mechanism by which the data provided in the host page, `index.html`, can be injected into the app.component's field ready for binding the the html template.

This is actually a much simplified version of my app where the intention is for the data to be used to initialise an Angular Service.

I appreciate that there may be more than one way to achieve this so different answers for each mechanism would be welcome and then people can up vote the preferred way.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option A** - read/access the variable yourself

***app.component.ts***

```
declare var someData: any;

@Component({
    ...
})
export class AppComponent {
    someDataFromTheHostPage: any = someData; // <= window.someData
}
```

**Option B** - use a decorator to read/access the variable

***app.component.ts***

```
import { HostPageVariable } from "./host-page-variable.decorator";

@Component({
    ...
})
export class AppComponent {
    @HostPageVariable("someData") // get the data from a variable called 'someData'
    someDataFromTheHostPage: any;

    @HostPageVariable() // auto-map the name of the variable - get the data from a variable called 'someData'
    someData: any;
}
```

***host-page-variable.decorator.ts***

```
export function HostPageVariable(name?: string) {
    return function OnChangeHandler(target: any, propertyKey: string): void {
        if (name == undefined) {
            name = propertyKey;
        }
        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
            get(): any {
                return window[name];
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Philipp! I must admit I was trying to avoid referencing the window variable from my Angular code.  Having said that the decorator solution looks like a good compromise.  I'll give it a few days and if no other good answers appear I'll accept this one.

Comment: We were also using the decorator approach at first, but we switched to a service which returns an `Observable` of that window variable, so we can easily replace the service implementation if we ever need to get the data asynchronously from the server.