# How all components & services can access Web.Config Keys defined in web.config of MVC+Angular5 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, angular5

I have MVC + Angular 5 application and some app-keys defined in web.config. I am able to access the keys in Index.cshtml file uisng the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webConfigKeyValues = new Object();
    webConfigKeyValues = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.WebConfigKeyValues));
</script>

<app-root></app-root>
```

My Angular 5 app consists of multiple feature modules. How can I access `webConfigKeyValues` in all feature modules, components, and services

Comment: Have a look at this question. It might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308111/how-do-you-initialise-an-angular-4-model-from-the-serving-asp-net-mvc-page

Comment: @Philipp: Thanks for the link. But my application has many modules and components. And these WebConfigKeyValues are very much needed when the angular application starts and are also used then throughout the application. So I am looking at a more refined approach where this can be injected at angular app start and can then be referenced later.

Comment: Well you could still use a similar approach as the one I linked but rather use e.g. an `InjectionToken` referencing the value of `webConfigKeyValues `.

Comment: @Philipp: Can you please provide any reference link where InjectionToken can be used like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47308943/1648800),
which describes how to reference a global variable directly or via a `decorator`, it is also possible to use an `InjectionToken` to get the values you passed to the JavaScript scope. ([Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgxx6x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts))

You can define the **token** as following

```
export const MY_WEBCONFIG_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<any>('Data from cshtml',   
{
    providedIn: 'root',
    factory: () => window["webConfigKeyValues"]
});
```

And then `Inject` that token into the `components` and `services` that rely on that data.

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(
        @Inject(MY_WEBCONFIG_TOKEN) private token: any
    ) { }
}
```

**EDIT**

For Angular version **5.x** you need to use a `ValueProvider`([Docs](https://v5.angular.io/api/core/ValueProvider)) to assign a value to an `InjectionToken`.

```
export const MY_WEBCONFIG_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<any>('Data from cshtml',);
```

***.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        { provide: MY_WEBCONFIG_TOKEN, useValue: window["webConfigKeyValues"] }
    ]
    ...
}})
export class MyModule { }
```

Comment: I am using Angular 5.2 which does not support InjectionToken with more than 1 parameter. Can you suggest for Angular 5.2

Comment: @Quest I've updated my answer to also reflect that approach in angular 5.x

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. Angular is a client-side framework, and from the browser it is not possible to access the web.config.

On the other hand, you can create some user control in MVC and add that in every cshtml file.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I can pass web.Config keys from ViewBag To JavaScript as shown in the code snippet. Now, what I can't resolve it how this value can be accessed by Angular 5 module